# Merge two images and serve as base64?

Tags: php, base64

Is it possible to merge two images as one AND serve them as a base64?

I am guessing no as there isn't a genuine real image but figured I would ask in case I am misunderstanding something.

For example I have the following - img.php file:

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('myimg.png');
$src = imagecreatefrompng('myimg1.png');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Is it possible at all to then

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents(img.php)))
```

Obviously i have attempted and its not working, so I am curious if I am just doing it wrong, or if its just not possible.

**UPDATING QUESTION**

So apparently it should be working but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the very basic code:

```
$abs_path = '/home/user/web_dir/path/to/img.php';
$rel_path = '/path/to/img.php';
$data = file_get_contents($abs_path);
echo $data; // should return crazy characters on the screen
echo '<br><img src="'.$rel_path.'">'; // should return the image as an image
```

The image returns perfectly, the $data returns nothing. Both paths are correct. No errors are returned.

If I run a

```
$test = base64_encode($data);
echo $test;
```

the base64 produced, does not return a valid image. just an empty container.

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? That certainly _is_ possible, why shouldn't it? Such a "merged" image is nothing but an image.

Comment: @arkascha I updated the question.

Comment: The definition of "merge" is not so clear here... can you please explain exactly what you are trying to do with the two images?

Comment: @Dekel erm.... okay??? the definition of merge that I am using is the same one used by imagecopymerge() from php. What I am trying to do with the images is fairly straight forward... imagealphablending(), imagesavealpha(), imagecopymerge(), output, encode as base 64, echo.

Comment: Your usage of `file_get_contents` is wrong. currently what you are doing is `file_get_contents('/home/user/web_dir/path/to/img.php');` (which gives the content of your php code, not the returned data of php running `img.php`)

Comment: What would be proper usage. I have never tried to do this with a php generated image, only actual images. With an actual image, the file_get_contents works perfectly when I hand it a image from the filesystem?